# How can a client decrypt an AES encrypted file by SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, encryption, aes

I am new to the AES encryption and reading about it.

We used to send data in `.csv` format with MD5 encryption but last week I got a requirement to send the data in AES encrypted format to client rather than MD5.

I have read some internet I did the following step

```
-- Create database key
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'Password123'

-- Create self-signed certificate 
CREATE CERTIFICATE Certificate1
WITH SUBJECT = 'Protect Data';
GO

-- Create symmetric key
CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY SymmetricKey1 
WITH ALGORITHM = AES_256
ENCRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE Certificate1;
GO
```

Then to encrypt the data I have used

```
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY SymmetricKey1
DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE Certificate1;

 Select EncryptByKey (Key_GUID('SymmetricKey1'),columnName) 
 From TableName

CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY SymmetricKey1;
```

I tried to encrypt and decrypt and It works fine and I have sent the data but client has a different server want to decrypt the file and they are asking me to send the KEY
I suppose the key is 'SymmetricKey1'

But Client is not able to decrypt it.
Now my question is if the certificate and symmetric key is in 1 SQL server(suppose india) and client want to decrypt the file in some other server what exactly I need to provide him.DO I need to create the same certificate and key on the client server or something else.

I may sound little stupid but sorry I could not find much in internet